# C# and Unity - Boolean works in one direction but not in reverse?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I encountered this error when attempting to create some game logic for a character impacting a wall. On impact, an event is triggered. I want that event to not trigger again on subsequent impacts to the same object.

The following code does NOT work (the events are not triggered):

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class CrashDetector : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] ParticleSystem finishEffect;
    [SerializeField] float delayTime = 5f;
    bool counterOne;
    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if ((other.tag == "Respawn") && (counterOne))
        {
            counterOne = false;
            FindObjectOfType<PlayerController>().DisableControls();
            finishEffect.Play();
            GetComponent<AudioSource>().Play(); 
            Invoke("ReloadScene", delayTime); 
        }
    }
        
    void ReloadScene()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(0);
    }
}
```

The following code DOES work (the only difference is that the Booleans have switched places, so `counterOne` defaults to `False`):

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class CrashDetector : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] ParticleSystem finishEffect;
    [SerializeField] float delayTime = 5f;
    bool counterOne = false;
    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if ((other.tag == "Respawn") && (!counterOne))
        {
            counterOne = true;
            FindObjectOfType<PlayerController>().DisableControls();
            finishEffect.Play();
            GetComponent<AudioSource>().Play(); 
            Invoke("ReloadScene", delayTime); 
        }
    }
        
    void ReloadScene()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(0);
    }
}
```

I was expecting both versions to function in the same way.

Comment: Can you point out in the first example that doesn't work where `counterOne` is set to true? If it is never true then this condition is never satisfied. `if ((other.tag == "Respawn") && (counterOne))`

Comment: The name `counterOne` is confusing. This is not a counter and it is not clear what `true` and `false` mean in this context. What about `hasCrashed`? Here, the meaning of `true` and `false` are clear.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer. I was under the mistaken belief that Bools are set to True automatically. I realise my mistake now and that the Bool was false initially.

Comment: Every not explicitly initialized class field is initialized to an internal representation consisting of all bits set to 0.

Comment: You can click the checkmark to mark your own answer as accepted and to close the question.